# django url pattern to match uuid

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am using Django 1.11. I am trying to get url pattern to match uuid but it does not work. I have tried more than 3 times but I am still getting error :

> Using the URLconf defined in eMarket.urls, Django tried these URL
>   patterns, in this order:
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/view/49c26740-2211-4cc9-971b-5ff62ddc2e0e/

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^view/(?P<slug>\b[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}\b(-\b[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}\b){3}-\b[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}\b)$', viewProduct, name="view"),
    url('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: What are all those `\b` elements doing in there?

Comment: i don't exactly i just copy it here, because everything is working with int id but when i change to uuid it is require the url pattern which can meet so i never done before that why i am asking for help

Comment: when a user clicked view the url should be like:

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/view/49c26740-2211-4cc9-971b-5ff62ddc2e0e/

Comment: try adding a trailing slash to the end of the pattern: `...)/?$`. Also, word boundaries (`\b`) are safe to remove.

Comment: path(r'^view/(?P<slug>[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}(-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}){3}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{12})/', viewProduct, name="view"),

Comment: still do nothing

Answer (score 2):

Could you use the django native [UUID path converter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#path-converters) instead of trying to manually create the regex?

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/view/49c26740-2211-4cc9-971b-5ff62ddc2e0e/"

m = re.search("(?P<slug>[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}(-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}){3}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{12})", url)
print(m.group(0))

gives:
49c26740-2211-4cc9-971b-5ff62ddc2e0e
```

Comment: path(r'^view/(?P<slug>[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}(-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}){3}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{12})', viewProduct, name="view"),

Comment: can you define *not working* ? what is the error you get ?

Comment: this the error:          Using the URLconf defined in eMarket.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

Comment: urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', homePage),
    url(r'^about/', aboutPage),
    url(r'^contact/', contactPage),
  
    url(r'^create_products/', addProducts),
    path(r'^view/(?P<slug>[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}(-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}){3}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{12})', viewProduct, name="view"),
    url(r'^search/', searchProduct, name="search"),  #name="search"

    url(r'^login/', loginPage),
    url(r'^register/', signupPage),

    url('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

Comment: pls. go through the Django docs and try to debug by excluding all other possibilities for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing so far i can imagine that could cause issues with the URL resolver: you are using a capturing group within your named `slug` group. This way Django will receive the full match plus **2** groups, which could avoid a proper URL resolution. You can check this quickly on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tQKwJf/1)

[image]

While using a non-capturing group (`?:`) for the repeating pattern, it will return only the named capturing group - again on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tQKwJf/2)

[image]

So, can you try `(?P<slug>[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}(?:-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}){3}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{12})` - because other than that, i see really no issues in your urlpattern.